# python-igraph: cannot decompose directed graph (neither STRONG nor WEAK)

Tags: python, python-3.x, igraph

Using python-igraph 0.7.1 (Python 3.4.8), I want to **decompose a directed graph into all unconnected subgraphs**. However, `g.decompose(mode=WEAK)` fails:

```
igraph._igraph.InternalError: Error at components.c:469: only 'IGRAPH_WEAK' is implemented, Invalid value
```

As the error message and google (e.g. [click](http://igraph-help.nongnu.narkive.com/JUljwz0R/extracting-sub-graph)) tells me, `STRONG` decomposition is not implemented and thus expected to fail, however **`WEAK` decomposition SHOULD work**. Well, it doesn't for me!

Here's a minimal example:

```
from igraph import Graph, WEAK
g = Graph(directed=True)
g.add_vertices(4)
g.add_edges([(0, 1), (2, 3)])
g.decompose(mode=WEAK) # <= FAILS!
```

I've tried `mode="weak"`, `mode="WEAK"`, `mode=WEAK`, and `mode=1`, and always get the same error.

Is there maybe a **workaround**, i.e. a **set of some other commands that lead to the same result?** (Note that I'm not really familiar with graph theory, so I might miss something obvious in this regard.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there maybe a workaround, i.e. a set of some other commands that lead to the same result?

Indeed, I've found a workaround that seems to work:

```
from igraph import graph, WEAK
g = Graph(directed=True)
g.add_vertices(6)
g.vs["ts"] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2] # timesteps
g.add_edges([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5)])

# sgs = g.decompose(mode=WEAK) # fails!
#< workaround
g.to_undirected() # we won't need 'g' anymore afterwards
sgs = g.decompose(mode=WEAK)
for sg in sgs:
    sg.to_directed(mutual=True)
    es_del = sg.es.select(lambda e: e.graph.vs[e.source]["ts"] > e.graph.vs[e.target]["ts"])
    sg.delete_edges(es_del)
#>
```

I convert the original directed graph to an unidirected graph, decompose it into subgraphs, convert all subgraphs back to directed graphs with edges in both directions, and remove all edges that point in the wrong direction. Of course if the original graph should be retained, we should make a copy of it first (or convert it back to a directed graph after decomposition).

**Warning:** Be aware that edge attributes seem to be lost when converting the directed graph to undirected! As far as I can see, they need to be restored manually (at least that's what I'm doing).